# Bloodhound JS clears LocalStorage on load

Tags: javascript, requirejs, local-storage, bloodhound

The moment when I require the Bloodhound JS library (v 1.2.1),

```
var Bloodhound = require('bloodhound-js');
```

the localstorage is wiped clean. I am storing some values there so right now I have a work-around in place where I read all the values, require Bloodhound, and then write them back to localstorage.

This is not a very nice solution though, so I was wondering if there is anyway to make Bloodhound not clear the Localstorage on load.

Comment: Have you found any better solution? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Still an issue. That took too long to isolate as Bloodhound in a large project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This build has fixed the issue by using a key prefix, so it can selectively clean down.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twitter/typeahead.js/master/dist/bloodhound.min.js

Comment: Which version should has this new fix?

Comment: This is a totally separate build from the broken project at http://github.com/pqx/bloodhound. I've used the latest files from the Twitter git hub. I assume that there was a fork in a time long ago.